# Merge two hash as sub-hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby

What I have:

```
{
  :url=>"http://localhost:something",
  :platformName=>"Windows",
  :foodName=>"taco",
  :Version=>"1",
  :browser=>"Edge"
}
```

These values were entered by the user in different HashMaps so I just made the input into a single hash for the ease, but the method called is like this:

```
def initialize(opts)
     @object = super Class::SuperClass.for(:remote,hash)
    end
```

What I want the hash to look like is some thing like this:

```
hash =   {
          :url=>"http://localhost:something", 
          :SubHash=> {
              :url=>"http://localhost:something",
              :platformName=>"Windows",
              :foodName=>"taco",
              :Version=>"1",
              :browser=>"Edge"
          }
        }
```

Comment: Where do those other fields come from? It's always best if you at least try to solve this, and even better, that you express it all in Ruby code as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Hash#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-slice) and [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge) to get what you want:

```
hash = {
  :url=>"http://localhost:something",
  :platformName=>"Windows",
  :foodName=>"taco",
  :Version=>"1",
  :browser=>"Edge"
}

output = hash.slice(:url).merge(SubHash: hash)
# => {
#   :url=>"http://localhost:something",
#   :SubHash=>{
#     :url=>"http://localhost:something",
#     :platformName=>"Windows",
#     :foodName=>"taco",
#     :Version=>"1",
#     :browser=>"Edge"
#   }
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do

```
hash_a = { foo: bar }
hash_b = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

hash_a[:sub_hash] = hash_b
```

which will result in

```
{
  foo: bar
  sub_hash:
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
}
```